# How do I control what colors are used when a user switches between Light and Dark mode in Android

Tags: android, themes

Suppose I have my own two custom defined themes in the styles.xml, one for Dark and one for Light. When a user goes into their smartphones settings and change to dark mode, how do I have my application use my own custom dark theme? Same with my Light theme.

In general, I suppose my question is more like how do I control what color my application uses when a user changes between light and dark mode. I do not want to use the default colors that come in each mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the colors that you use in your layout and put them in `values-night/colors.xml`. So, in light theme `values/colors.xml` will be used and in the night theme, `values-night/colors.xml` will be used.

Let's say you have a color assigned to a button, you write following line, make sure the color name is same:

`values/colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorButton">#6d85c9</color>
```

`values-night/colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorButton">@color/colorWhite</color>
```

And then you can assign the color to the button you do normally.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: and to switch b/w light and dark mode you have to call  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES/NO)